# Oracle SQL Create function or procedure returning a table

Tags: sql, oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

In SQL Server, I can just use 'RETURNS TABLE' and it will do the job. But I can't find how to do the same in Oracle SQL

I have the following SELECT statement that needs to be put in a function or procedure:

```
SELECT a.CodAcord, a.Descr
FROM FreqSoce f
LEFT JOIN Acord a ON a.CodAcord = f.CodAcord
WHERE f.codSoce = codSoce;
```

`codSoce`  is an INTEGER IN parameter, and I need to return `a.CodAcord` and `a.Descr` as result from my function/procedure.
Is there a simple way to do this? Without having to deal with temp variables and/or advanced content...

**EDIT:** Aditional info:
 - I need to return `a.CodAcord` and `a.Descr`, but when I did some research to know how to return more than one variable using SQL Functions or Procedures, all I could find was that this was only possible by returning a TABLE. If there's a way to return more than one item from a Function or Procedure, please let me know.
 - The use of Functions or Procedures is strictly required.
 - I'm using SQL Developer.

Comment: Do you need to return a.CodAcord and a.Descr for a given codScoce, or do you need to return a table? I don't see the connection. Also: do you need a procedure for this, or is the use of bind variables sufficient? What do you use to interface with Oracle: SQL*Plus? Toad? SQL Developer? Each has its means for allowing you to "input" a bind variable and produce the output based on that. Please clarify and we can take it from there.

Comment: Aditional information provided, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a table as a return value from function by using a pipelined table function. Please see the example below:

```
-- Create synthetic case
CREATE TABLE Acord AS
SELECT rownum CodAcord, 'Description ' || rownum Descr
  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE FreqSoce AS
SELECT rownum CodSoce, rownum CodAcord
  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

-- Test dataset
SELECT a.CodAcord, a.Descr
  FROM FreqSoce f
  LEFT JOIN Acord a ON a.CodAcord = f.CodAcord
 WHERE f.CodSoce = 10;

-- Here begins actual code
-- Create an object type to hold each table row
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_acord AS OBJECT(
  CodAcord NUMBER,
  Descr    VARCHAR2(40)
);
/

-- Create a collection type to hold all result set rows
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_acord AS TABLE OF typ_acord;
/

-- Our function that returns a table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAcord(pCodSoce IN NUMBER)
RETURN tab_acord PIPELINED
AS
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT a.CodAcord, a.Descr
              FROM FreqSoce f
              LEFT JOIN Acord a ON a.CodAcord = f.CodAcord
             WHERE f.CodSoce = pCodSoce)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (typ_acord(x.CodAcord, x.Descr));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- Testing the function (please note the TABLE operator)
SELECT * FROM TABLE(getAcord(5));
```

Comment: Best answer, that I have found so far, to this problem. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Take the following as a code template:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tacord AS
    TYPE ttabAcord IS TABLE OF ACord%ROWTYPE;
END tacord;
/
show err

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tacord AS
BEGIN
    NULL;
END tacord;
/
show err

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo RETURN tacord.ttabAcord AS
    to_return   tacord.ttabAcord;
BEGIN
               SELECT a.*
    BULK COLLECT INTO to_return
                 FROM FreqSoce f
            LEFT JOIN Acord a ON a.CodAcord = f.CodAcord
                WHERE f.codSoce = codSoce
                    ;
    RETURN to_return;
END demo;
/
show err
```

Key points:

- `%ROWTYPE` represents the datatype of a database table's record
- `BULK COLLECT INTO` inserts a complete result set into a plsql data structure
- Iteration over the table contents is availabel by the plsql collection methods, namely `.FIRST`, `.LAST`, `.NEXT`.

Comment: the code compiles, but executing using SQL Developer returns nothing, is there a special way to execute this?

Comment: So what is the common way to execute the procedure?

Comment: In the example above, @collapsar uses a `FUNCTION`. To use a function in PL/SQL context you have to use the value returned, e.g. assign function result to some variable.